# JMeter Parallel Controller having two transaction controller issue

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a Parallel controller and inside this I have 2 transaction controllers.

My one transaction controller passes but other one throws an assertion error.

But in response tree, both transaction controller shows as fail through all steps in the first controller is pass.

Is this due to parallel controller?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's part of [Parallel Controller limitations](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md):

> Parallel Controller does not support work with Transaction Controller so if used you can get an unexpected results. If you decide to use these controllers together familiarize yourself with already known problems that described in [roadmap](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#roadmap)

Comment: Thanks that explain things

Comment: @ShashankGarg if it helped you can accept the answer by clicking on V sign to the left of the answer